# LU factorization

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a nonsingular $n\times n$  matrix and suppose that Gaussian 
elimination with partial pivoting has been applied to produce $PA = LU$, where :
 - $P$ is a permutation,
 - $L$ is a unit lower triangle
 - $U$ is upper triangular.

> Show that $$\|A\|_{\infty}≥\frac{\|U^{-1}\|_{\infty}}{n}$$

Comment: And what is $u$? Is it the same as $U$?

Comment: Excuse me.I mean is U.

Comment: This cannot be correct.  Let's look at $1\times 1$ matrices, then $P = L = [1]$, and $A = U = [a]$.  Then in this special case your inequality becomes $|a| \ge |a|^{-1}$.  This clearly isn't true is $a$ is sufficiently small.